# Apply standard deviation to a Data Frame Split by Factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to apply the sd function to my data frame but it does not work:

```
sdsd <- by(nowna[, 1:16], nowna$stamm, sd)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

do you have any idea why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you mark your question as answered if it has indeed been answered.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(plyr)
dt <- data.frame(age=rchisq(20,10),group=sample(1:2,20,rep=T))

dt
age group
1   9.908015     2
2  11.415043     2
3   7.849433     2
4   8.850696     2
5   6.194783     2
6  11.111339     2
7   9.789127     2
8  10.844352     1
9   8.686503     2
10 21.579142     2
11 11.750417     1
12  3.719226     1
13 12.086820     1
14 13.562351     1
15  4.636543     2
16 12.648083     1
17 10.780387     2
18 10.651318     2
19  5.976533     1
20 13.546345     2

ddply(dt,~group,summarise,mean=mean(age),sd=sd(age))
group     mean       sd
1     1 10.08397 3.728750
2     2 10.38451 4.082198
```

another one line variant using new package `data.table`.

```
dtf <- data.frame(age=rchisq(100000,10),group=factor(sample(1:10,100000,rep=T)))
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[,list(mean=mean(age),sd=sd(age)),by=group]
```

Using `Aggregate Function`

```
aggregate(dt$age, by=list(dt$group), FUN=sd)
  Group.1        x
1       1 3.728750
2       2 4.082198
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the standard deviation of *multiple* columns, you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(nowna[1:16], list(nowna$stamm), sd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have an object assigned to `sd`.  Notice how I recreate your error by assigning a value to the `sd` variable below:

```
by(warpbreaks[, 1], warpbreaks$wool, sd)
warpbreaks$wool: A
# [1] 15.85143
# ------------------------------------------------------ 
#   warpbreaks$wool: B
# [1] 9.300921
sd <- 5
by(warpbreaks[, 1], warpbreaks$wool, sd)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
rm(sd)
by(warpbreaks[, 1], warpbreaks$wool, sd)
# warpbreaks$wool: A
# [1] 15.85143
# ------------------------------------------------------ 
#   warpbreaks$wool: B
# [1] 9.300921
```

You need to `rm(sd)`

Comment: you are right, I just had another object called sd. That was also a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @alexmulo, you should mark your question as answered if it has indeed been answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sd(nowna[,1:16])` probably won't work. This will work:

```
apply(nowna[,1:16], 2, function(x) by(x, nowna$stamm, sd))
```